# Como consumir event-stream com nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho uma aplicação nodejs que precisa consumir um endpoint que me devolve um `text/event-stream`. A aplicação que emite esses eventos é feita com java e empacota um dado dentro de um objeto `ServerSentEvent` contendo id, event, retry, comment e data, onde `data` é a minha mensagem.
Para consumir o endpoint tentei utilizar alguma lib de `eventSource` mas nenhuma funcionou como esperado. Agora estou tentando consumir utilizando a lib `http`, desse modo:

```js
http.get({
    agent: false
    , path: "/streaming"
    , hostname: "localhost"
    , port: 8080
}, (res) => {
    res.on('data', data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
});
```

Observando o objeto `data` que é retornado, percebo que ele é do tipo Buffer. Porém não consigo convertê-lo para um formato que eu consiga manipular.
Qual deveria ser a forma correta de consumir esse endpoint? Continuar buscando uma lib de `EventSource` ou há uma forma de consumir utilizando a lib `http`?

PS: a aplicação Node não carrega nada no browser, é apenas backend. Node v10.16.3

#### Editado

Um projeto de exemplo contendo o mínino possível para testar pode ser visto aqui: https://github.com/josecarlosweb/sse-emit-test

Comment: Consegue fornecer um exemplo mínimo verificável? Porque se as que você testou não funcionaram deve ser devido à alguma particularidade da sua API

Comment: Boa ideia @Sorack. Criando aqui agora.

Comment: Adicionei um projeto de exemplo

Comment: Se é um stream, a informação não chega toda de uma vez, você precisa ir consumindo aos poucos do buffer. Como fazer isso depende da biblioteca que está usando do lado do cliente, mas imagino que todas que suportem streams ofereçam um modo de lidar com isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como [**bfavaretto**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) citou, você precisa consumir aos poucos para formar a resposta completa. Basta usar os eventos:

```
// ...
const partes = [];
res.on('data', (parte) => partes.push(parte));
res.on('end', () => console.log(Buffer.concat(partes).toString('utf8')));
// ...
```

---

> [**Stream - Event: `data`**](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data)
>
> The '`data`' event is emitted whenever the `stream` is relinquishing ownership of a chunk of data to a consumer.

Em tradução

> O evento '`data`' é emitido sempre que o `stream` está cedendo a propriedade de um pedaço de dados para um consumidor.

---

> [**Stream - Event: '`end`'**](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end)
>
> The '`end`' event is emitted when there is no more data to be consumed from the `stream`.

Em tradução livre:

> O evento '`end`' é emitido quando não há mais dados a serem consumidos do `stream`.

---

> [`Buffer.concat`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength)
>
> Returns a new `Buffer` which is the result of concatenating all the `Buffer` instances in the list together.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna um novo `Buffer` que é resultado da junção de todas as instâncias de `Buffer` juntos na lista.

---

> [`buf.toString`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end)
>
> Decodes `buf` to a `string` according to the specified character encoding in `encoding`.

Em tradução livre:

> Decodifica `buf` para uma `string` de acordo com a tabela específica em `encoding`.